# Anyone know how to make time remapping animated

Tags: rendering, animation

I want to make a scene which goes from normal speed to slow motion then normal again
this question was asked a while ago but on a previous build

I'm not sure how to do this and it's not just particle effects and simulations, i want animated objects to be manipulated too without having to go through the process of changing the frames of every object